# How to export database as sql in asp net core web api from client side

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using Asp.Net Core Web API and PostgreSQL for the database. How can the admins take the database backup as .sql file and can restore the data back whenever they want. I have nine tables.

Comment: You probably _shouldn't_ do this over a web API.  It sounds like a possible security nightmare. If you must, `pg_dump` is probably where you would start.

Comment: The table doesn't contain sensitive data. I wanna know how to implement it using csharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pg_dump`. Your C# code may look like below:

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine("PostgreSQL", "postgresql-backup.bat");
var host = "For Example:localhost";
var port = "For Example:5432";
var user = "For Example:postgres";
var database = "Your databaseName";
var outputPath = "Your localDatabasePath";

// use pg_dump, specifying the host, port, user, database to back up, and the output path.
// the host, port, user, and database must be an exact match with what's inside your pgpass.conf (Windows)
startInfo.Arguments = $@"{host} {port} {user} {database} ""{outputPath}""";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Restoring a database is similar, but using `pg_restore`.

For more details, you can refer to [this GitHub](https://github.com/joemoceri/database-toolkit).

Hope this can help you.